# Is there any print statement in db2 just like oracle

Tags: sql, plsql, db2, db2-400

Is there( db2 database) any equivalent of DBMS_OUTPUT in Oracle or PRINT in SQL Server for DB2 or do I need to jump over my head again for this sort of thing?

please provide some code also.

Answer (score 3):

IBM's DB2 version `9.7` or later actually comes with a `DBMS_OUTPUT` module which appears to be able to do the same thing as Oracle's version.  From the [DB2 documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0053551.html), `DBMS_OUTPUT` can be called from within a stored procedure, e.g.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON@

CREATE PROCEDURE proc1()
BEGIN
    CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( 'H' );
    CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( 'e' );
    CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( 'l' );
    CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( 'l' );
    CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( 'o' );
    CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( '.' );
    CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE;
  END@
CALL proc1@
```

This would output `Hello.` to the console.

Note that you also need to make sure that the output from `DBMS_OUTPUT` is being redirected to the standard output:

> The procedures in this module allow you to work with the message buffer. Use the command line processor (CLP) command SET SERVEROUTPUT ON to redirect the output to standard output.

Comment: i want to use print statement in store procedure just like oracle sapport 
 dbms_output.put_line('Hello Reader!');

when procedure run than Hello Reader! is print.

Comment: @raj Doesn't the code sample I've given you above show how that is possible?

Comment: i am using CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( 'H' ); this statement in own procedure  but in result H is not print.

Comment: What version of DB2 are you using?

Comment: Database Connection Information

 Database server        = DB2/LINUXX8664 10.5.6
 SQL authorization ID   = DB2INST1
 Local database alias   = TNBDR

Comment: @raj Try using `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` to make sure your print statements are going to the place you expect them to be.

Comment: db2inst1@ITLDEVTNSRDHDB:~> db2 SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DB20000I  The SET SERVEROUTPUT command completed successfully.
 this is done but in output window mohit is not print

Comment: @raj I'm out of ideas then.  I'll leave my answer here in case it helps someone else get your problem solved.  Here, have an upvote +1

Comment: Your procedure works just fine.  If you're not seeing the output, please update your question with the exact command you're executing and all output generated by that command.